# How to make ListView to take the entire space?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have listViews nested inside a Expanded which is further  inside a column. I want the list to take up the entire space.

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 10,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'AAAAA',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: false,
              itemCount: 10,
           
              // reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                Container(color:Colors.white,child: Text('hello'))
              
            ),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have used expanded , still my list view isn't taking the entire space

[image: heres the example]

I have deliberately added the column, because I want to have a text field inside it below the Listview.

**EDIT**

This is the final layout what I want to achieve, But as I could see the issue is with the List view not taking the whole space.
https://ibb.co/t8LbYBX here is the example

Comment: add to Column crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. The UI remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

remove the Text () from the container that will work

> itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
> Text('hello')

Comment: But still it didn't work, you can check it here https://ibb.co/HzdZwJV , i have added the dev tool screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it... few examples:

```
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 10, // screen size / itemCount
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text('hello'),
        ),
      ),
```

or

```
    body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: List.generate(10, (_) => Text('hello')),
      ),
```

Comment: The second solution isnt the one I want. I woild be having a Text field below the list view, Similar to a chat UI, so I need Expanded. Same thing with the first one. I would be using a texfiled, below so I want the list to dynamically take up the left over space of screen (exculidng the sapce of text field)

Comment: Please update description then with exactly what you need

Comment: I have updated, If you please could have a look

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your list with a container and set the height to 100% of the screen then subtract the height of the appbar

```
Container(
       height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.heigh-AppBar().preferredSize.height,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: false,
                      itemCount: 10,
                   
                      // reverse: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        Container(color:Colors.white,child: Text('hello'))
                      
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: nope it didn't work, i did this code like https://codeshare.io/5NDblo

Answer (score 0):

Remove column
Add
Container(
height:double.infinity,
width:double.infinity
Child:listview (.......

Comment: I have deliberately added the column , Because in column I want to have a text field.